# How to limit log file size in Apache2

Tags: linux, web, apache-2.2

Log files in /var/log/apache2/ are too big.
I want to limit the file size.
Is it possible to store only the recent 100 lines?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look here:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/rotatelogs.html

You can save a logfile per day and delete old ones automatically with a cronjob.
The lines can be done with a limitation of the file size (I think it is not necessary of it will be 120 or 100 lines?).